# Aforge video - Camera is use by another device

Tags: c#, aforge

I am using Aforge Video for accessing the camera of my computer. Things where good and working but my problem now is when an another application is using the camera first. The Start() method of Aforge Video doesn't fail even the camera is used by another application. Is there a way to check if camera is already used in AForge Video?

Comment: If it _doesn't_ fail, what's the problem then?

Comment: Well as you know when the camera is used by another application it cannot be use by the application.  That's the problem then. How will you inform the user that the camera is used by the another application when your Start method doesn't fail if the camera is used by the another application.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. So the `Start` method "seems" to work, but you don't actually get any pictures without exceptions or anything...

Comment: Yes @Fildor, that exactly what happen.

Comment: I found out a workaround. I just add checking if the newframe event is called.

Comment: If that works, you may want to answer your own question. That's totally accepted (even encouraged) on SO, because it's helpful to others in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I implemented to handle this problem:

```
     private async void StartCameraAsync()
    {
        if (SFilterInfo != null)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(SFilterInfo.MonikerString);
            
            VideoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame);
            VideoCaptureDevice.Start();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            //Set false when video started
            IsImageGrab =false;
        }
    }

  private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
       //Set true so that you will know that images in the camera is received
            IsImageGrab = true;
            System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();

            bi.Freeze();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        
        }
    }
```